# How to create left and right fixed sidebar with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In a Bootstrap 5 markup structure, can you use 2 `<nav>` elements to create a left and right fixed sidebar with content in the middle?  Something like this:

```html
<nav>
  <div>left sidebar</div>
</nav>
<main>
  <div>main content</div>
</main>
<nav>
  <div>right sidebar</div>
</nav>
```

What would the basic bootstrap5 classes look like/css to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid-system. One way to do this is just make assign those grid-column values into whatever you prefer inside a single row (i used 2 - 8 - 2 for this demonstration)

Then you could use `position: sticky` and your preferred positioning values on the nested element inside each `nav`. This way the content will stick to the screen while scrolling through the main content.

```css
/* ----- Resetting styling/demo purpose ----- */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper.row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper.row>* {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/* ----- end ----- */

.col-md-2 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.col-md-2 div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.col-md-8 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  height: 175vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wrapper row">
  <nav class="col-md-2">
    <div>left sidebar</div>
  </nav>
  <main class="col-md-8">
    <div>main content</div>
  </main>
  <nav class="col-md-2">
    <div>right sidebar</div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div>left item, put me some width</div>
    <div class="flex-fill">content item, will fill remaining</div>
    <div>right item, put me some width</div>
</div>
```

As you said, side bars are fixed (you need to put them in some class with width), and middle one will expand to fill remaining width of parent

Comment: Thank you as well for your help and observation! Much appreciated